# Error when I try playground for Swift in Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I encountered the following error when I create and open a playground for Swift, any solution for it?

```
Error running playground.
Failed to prepare for communication with playground.
```

Comment: I think I got that the first time too. It went away for me after typing a few lines and saving I think.

Comment: I've gotten something like this a few times

Comment: 4 times in the first day. Using a macbook air.

Comment: None of the answers help me on Xcode 6.2 "stable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the restarting XCode 6 did not solve the problem. So I restarted the Mac. It worked afterwards.

This tutorial was helpful: http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start

Answer (score 23):

I'm experiencing the same problem, but restarting xCode6-beta seems to solve it.

Comment: Yep. For me, just closing and reopening the playground file did it.

Comment: Restarting the program does indeed fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 6.1.1

Creating playground using the path Xcode->Start and selecting "Get Started With a Playground" is giving "Error running playground. Unable to find suitable target device"

Creating playground using the path Xcode->File->New and then choosing playground => No errors